# How to transpile a script tag within an HTML document during a webpack build?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, transpiler

*Note: I am aware of https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone#usage and am not asking about transpiling in the browser.*

I'm wondering if *either* of the following is possible:

**Option 1 - Transpile stuff in an HTML file**

Say I have the following `src/index.html` with some inline ES6:

```
<!-- src/index.html -->
<h1>This is some HTML stuff...</h1>
<script>
     () => console.log('I am some inline JS.');
</script>
```

After some type of build end up with the following `dist/index.html` which has inline ES5:

```
<!-- dist/index.html -->
<h1>This is some HTML stuff...</h1>
<script>
    function() {
        console.log('I am some inline JS.');
    }
</script>
```

**Option 2 - Concatenate transpiled JS to an HTML file**

Say I have the following `src` files:

```
<!-- src/index.html -->
<h1>This is some HTML stuff...</h1>
```

and a JS which contains ES6:

```
// src/index.js
() => console.log('I am some JS from another file.');
```

After some type of build end up with the following `dist/index.html` which has inline ES5 concatenated to the bottom of the file in a `script` tag:

```
<!-- dist/index.html -->
<h1>This is some HTML stuff...</h1>
<script>
    function() {
        console.log('I am some JS from another file.');
    }
</script>
```

I've looked through a bunch of webpack loaders, but nothing seems to fit this. There may be a really simple solution, but what am I missing? Is there a babel plugin or webpack loader which could handle either of these.

P.S. I would prefer a setup with Option 1.

Comment: Option 3 : Write code that works in the enviroment it's intended to be used !

Comment: :) Thanks. I should mention, I would be supporting IE11 *and* modern browsers. I would like to write in ES6 but would be serving different versions of the final HTML depending on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Polymer team has a util that strips js from html. [Crisper](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/crisper). You can use that to strip the js from the script tags, then feed it to your transpiler, then inject it back into the html.

Comment: This is interesting. Thank you!